# Assembly and link of module with absolute addresses

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am attempting to make a module that will be located at an absolute address.  Any mention of OFFSET or attempt to CALL a subroutine causes the link to fail.

Example:

```
.8086

_TEXT   SEGMENT BYTE AT 440H
    ORG 4400H
    ASSUME  CS:_TEXT

START:
START_O EQU THIS WORD
;   MOV DI, OFFSET START
;   MOV DI,START_O
;   CALL SUBR
;   CALL SUBR_O


SUBR:
SUBR_O EQU $-7C00h
    RET


_TEXT   ENDS
    END
```

I am using the Microsoft MASM 5.0 assembler and associated linker.  Commands:

```
masm bull,bull,bull;
link bull;
```

If any one of the commented lines is uncommented masm will succeed, but the link will report:

```
BULL.OBJ(bull.ASM) : error L2001: fixup(s) without data
 pos: 41 Record type: 9C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a loader that will load this code at 00000:04400h, and the goal is to produce a .com file. In this case you don't need to specify the segment address.

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT    ;assume loaded at 00000h:04400h
        ASSUME  CS:_TEXT
        ORG     00000H
START:  MOV     DI,OFFSET CS:START
        CALL    SUBR
        RET
        ORG     07C00H-04400H
SUBR:   RET
_TEXT   ENDS
        END     START
```

Note - this will create a large .com file (14337 bytes long). If SUBR is an external piece of code, you may want to use something like this to create a small .com file:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT    ;assume loaded at 00000h:04400h
        ASSUME  CS:_TEXT
        ORG     00000H
START:  MOV     DI,OFFSET CS:START
        CALL    START+07C00H-04400H
        RET
_TEXT   ENDS
        END     START
```